# .Net7 upgrade of Azure Function project fails to run locally

Tags: visual-studio, azure-functions

I updated VS 2022 to the latest version and upgraded my Azure functions project to .Net7. I get error message when running the app from visual studio "There is no Functions runtime available that matches the version specified in the project.".  How do I fix this issue? Note that it runs fine in Azure.

csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="appsettings.Development.json" />
    <None Remove="appsettings.json" />
    <None Remove="appsettings.Production.json" />
    <None Remove="appsettings.staging.json" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="appsettings.Development.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="appsettings.Production.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="appsettings.staging.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets" Version="1.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.8.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Abstractions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.7.0" OutputItemType="Analyzer" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.10.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Azure" Version="1.6.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Visual Studio 2022 Info:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022
Version 17.5.1
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.5.1+33424.131
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.09032

Installed Version: Community

ADL Tools Service Provider   1.0
This package contains services used by Data Lake tools

ASA Service Provider   1.0

ASP.NET and Web Tools   17.5.317.37931
ASP.NET and Web Tools

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   17.5.317.37931
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0
Microsoft Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio

Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   17.5.317.37931
Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools

Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0
Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio

C# Tools   4.5.0-6.23123.11+271ccd71554f7d28d2f90551aafd0bdeb5d327aa
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Microsoft Azure Hive Query Language Service   2.6.5000.0
Language service for Hive query

Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Language Service   2.6.5000.0
Language service for Azure Stream Analytics

Microsoft Azure Tools for Visual Studio   2.9
Support for Azure Cloud Services projects

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

NuGet Package Manager   6.5.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/

Razor (ASP.NET Core)   17.5.2.2307502+8b3141d86b738daf2ca3ed9c15b12513071fc676
Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.

SQL Server Data Tools   17.2.40118.0
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

ToolWindowHostedEditor   1.0
Hosting json editor into a tool window

TypeScript Tools   17.0.20105.2003
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual Basic Tools   4.5.0-6.23123.11+271ccd71554f7d28d2f90551aafd0bdeb5d327aa
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Visual F# Tools   17.5.0-beta.23053.5+794b7c259d9646a7eb685dad865aa27da7940a21
Microsoft Visual F# Tools

Visual Studio IntelliCode   2.2
AI-assisted development for Visual Studio.
```

Also, I don't see .Net7 as a runtime option, if I try to create a new Azure functions project.

[image: Available runtime options]

[image: Programs - with .Net filter]

Comment: Have you installed [.NET 7 SDK & Runtime](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0) - https://i.imgur.com/Ce7Oh6a.png

Comment: I tried and it didn't help. (Attached image of Control panel -> Programs with .Net filter)

Answer (score 6):

When .NET 7 is not visible in the Visual Studio IDE on Azure Functions Context, try checking in the Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features, all are installed as expected but still not shown in the Visual Studio 2022 Latest Version IDE.

[image]

Glad @[*frosty*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2720421/frosty) that you have resolve the issue with the help of VS Dev Community Article #[10224478](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Sometimes-the-Visual-Studio-functions-wo/10224478)

> 1. Usually, the issue can be resolved by deleting **`%LocalAppData%\AzureFunctionsTools`** and re-lauch your Visual Studio IDE see if that works.
> 2. If that doesn’t work, go to VS IDE > Tools -> Options -> Projects & Solutions -> Azure Functions and click "**`check for updates`**". Then download and install the updates and see if that works.

[image]

Comment: Deleting %LocalAppData%\AzureFunctionsTools and then VS IDE > Tools -> Options -> Projects & Solutions -> Azure Functions and click "check for updates" solved the issue to me. Thanks!

Comment: Simply deleting %LocalAppData%\AzureFunctionsTools worked for me after upgrading to .NET 8.0, thank you!